# Sphinx readthedocs install directory has different layout than installing on my own machine. How to make them the same?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

When I run Sphinx on my machine it installs for example

developers/integration.rst into developers/integration.html

but on readthedocs it installs it in

developers/integration/index.html

This makes the use of relative links in any raw commands fail.

Is there a way to force my machine install to use the same directory structure as readthedocs? Or other solutions?

Comment: Please paste the contents of your `conf.py`. This should not happen by default. I don't know of any setting that would do this. Also did you do a `make clean` first? You might be looking at a cached or previously built file.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I cannot fit the conf.py into the comment box so here is the link. https://gitlab.com/petsc/petsc/-/blob/master/src/docs/sphinx_docs/conf.py

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I cannot fit the conf.py into the comment box so here is the link. https://gitlab.com/petsc/petsc/-/blob/master/src/docs/sphinx_docs/conf.py    I am pretty sure that it is not a cache issue. The read the docs can be found at https://docs.petsc.org/en/barry-2020-10-14-docs-integration/developers/integration/   a tarball can be found at https://gitlab.com/BarrySmith/test-project/-/issues/1

Comment: You must edit your question. I will not download an untrusted file.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the difference between the [Standalone HTML Builder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.html.StandaloneHTMLBuilder) and the [Directory HTML Builder](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/builders/index.html#sphinx.builders.dirhtml.DirectoryHTMLBuilder).  You can change the builder with the [sphinx-builder](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-file/v2.html#sphinx-builder) option of the read-the-doc configuration file, or change your build option on the command line by specifying it with `-b`.